# How do I define table columns in a base class and table names in a child class in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I need to have 2 separate tables with identical structures which seems like an inheritance scenario, but I don't want the base class to be associated with a table. The `Base` only exists to define the columns for the table(s) in the child class(es). [The `AbstractConcreteBase` docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.AbstractConcreteBase) led me to implement it this way:

in `status.py`:

```
class Base(AbstractConcreteBase):
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('date', DateTime(), nullable=False)

class Status1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status1'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': __tablename__,
        'concrete': True
    }

class Status2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status2'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': __tablename__,
        'concrete': True
    }
```

in `part.py`:

```
class Part(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'parts'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    status1 = relationship('Status1', uselist=True, backref=backref('status1', order_by='Status1.date'))
    status2 = relationship('Status2', uselist=True, backref=backref('status2', order_by='Status2.date'))
```

When attempting this, I get the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|Part|parts, expression 'Status1' failed to locate a name ("name 'Status1' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'package.Part'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is a Mixin class. Your base class should not inherit from the SQLAlchemy `declarative_base` if dont want to associate the base class with a table. A mixin will define the columns/table structure like you want. Your child classes then inherit from **both** the mixin and the `declarative_base`.

The mixin would be defined as follows:

```
class StatusMixin(object):
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('date', DateTime(), nullable=False)
```

The child classes become much simpler:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Status1(StatusMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status1'

class Status2(StatusMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status2'
```

Finally, your `relationship`s defined for the `Part` class are not correctly defined. To use `backref`s you need to have a foreign key defined in `status1` and `status2` that link them together:

```
class Status1(StatusMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status1'
    part_id = Column('part_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parts.id'))
```

The table defining the `relationship` that has a `backref` needs to have its own table name as the `backref` instead of the names of the `child1` and `child2` tables:

```
class Part(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'parts'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    status1 = relationship('Status1', uselist=True, backref=__tablename__)
    status2 = relationship('Status2', uselist=True, backref=__tablename__)
```